# Census Blocks with no buildings or structures

Tags: census, demography

In the 2020 decennial data there are blocks with population but they have no structures of any kind. It's a pretty insignificant number but I'd like to know what side of the road I should put these people.

[image: picture of a couple streets where 708 people are listed as living in the median]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 2):

I do not work for the US Census but do a lot of work with Census data on the behalf a US city. The short on how US Census blocks are created is by just taking feature classes of boundaries, streets, geographic features and doing a union on all those layers.

So some blocks will have no residents and some will have very few. This can lead to a case where a person can be identified by their recorded statistics. (e.g. A single family will be easily identified if their are the only black family in a Census block.) Part of protecting the identities of US residents is to inject statistical noise into the datasets.

To quote a comment I made on a [similar question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/70105/why-does-the-u-s-census-deliberately-transfer-population-to-neighboring-census) on the Politics.SE:

> There are publicly available papers that describe the methodology and more if you keep digging, @TechInquisitor You should not be able to exactly explain why there are 20 residents there in any particular block because the noise injection should be random and more-or-less unexplained otherwise it isn't very good obfuscation. BUT, the aggregate data should still be correct, useful, with a known level of noise or error.

So, answer is: you don't. You cannot know where those people came from, or how make it more 'correct'. You can only make your sample large enough that the inject noise is too small to impact you study, make note, or attempt to correct for it in your study. That is, adjust your sample size.

Comment: So it appears as an actual encoding error with the geographic placement of the housing units. Quoting the reply from the Census regional office: "These errors appear to be the result of the geographic placement of housing units".